# label not working with date select in cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, form-helpers, cakephp-3.4

I'm using form helper to input date select as follows

```
echo $this->Form->date('date_from', [
    'empty' => [
        'year' => 'Choose Year',
        'month' => 'Choose Month',
        'day' => 'Choose Date'
    ],
    'label' => 'Date From'
]);
```

But this is only showing select field and not the label **Date From**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like CakePHP3 form helper with `date` doesn't support `label` as parameter.

But this will generate exactly the same label as you want:

```
<?php
  echo $this->Form->label('Date From');
  echo $this->Form->date('date_from', [
 'empty' => [
    'year' => 'Choose Year',
    'month' => 'Choose Month',
    'day' => 'Choose Date'
 ],
]);
?>
```

See here: [Creating label in CakePHP3 form helper.](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-labels)

Comment: I know we can print label this way. Can't we print label along with date or time input field?

Comment: It looks like we can't..and if you see in documentation there is no any example for using label within date and time input field.

Comment: If you want to create labels with a single call, then you have to use the `control()` (previously `input()`) method. The type specific helper methods are explicitly ment to [**only create the input elements**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#generating-specific-types-of-controls). @AnujTBE

Answer (score 0):

You can add the label in your HTML code:

```
    <div class="input date">
        <label>My label</label>
        <?php echo $this->Form->date('from_date'); ?>
    </div>
```

The difference between the [Date Form Control](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-date-time-related-controls) and [Form Control](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/views/helpers/form.html#options-for-date-related-controls) is that the last one outputs the `div` wrapper and the `label` (among others).